# HtoI [HexaDecimal to Integer] - using Ascii codes

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have made following coding to convert a hexa decimal to integer. [My algorithm]

```
private static void ConvertFromBase16(string value)
    {
        value = value.ToUpper();
        int result = 0;
        int incrementor = 0;
        for (int i = value.Length-1; i >= 0; i-- )
        {
            char c = value[i];
            char number;
            if (c > 64)
            {
                number = (char)(c - 55); //Ascii character for A start from 65.in hex
                                        //its 10, so i have subtracted 55 from it.
            }
            else
            {
                number = (char)(c - 48); //Ascii character for 0 is 48, so subtracting 
                                         //48
            }
            int n = (int) number;
            result += (number* (int) Math.Pow(16 , incrementor));
            incrementor++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

As you can see, in the above code I've used ascii characters for conversion than using traditional case conditions.
I'm quite a bit doubtful, whether this will work in all OS and create proper results.

Please can some one suggest me whether this is correct approach and wont be error prone?

PS:
I know, converting using .net default library method int.parse with globalization cultures. I want to do this manually in order to learn data structures concept. So please dont post anything handy from default .net library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the characters themselves to check and subtract, being independent of the actual charset.
So instead of, for example

```
number = (char)(c - 48);
```

use

```
number = (char)(c - '0');
```

This way you let the framework/compiler do the conversation to an actual charset for you. This is the way this is usually done in C/C++ too.

In general with C# you don't need to worry about your code working "in all OS", because officially it will only run in Windows anyways. But if the default charset is ever changed then your code will break.

Comment: Nice. And in the if case use (c>='A')

Comment: ASCII codes are generic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII it wont be change i believe. Thanks wutz for your suggestion and how its done it c or c++. Thought of ensure whether am in correct path. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate that your string contains only valid HEX numbers and throw exception if you see a not valid one.

Comment: I have already did this, in fact i immediately sending converted hexa decimal to this method. This is not at all a problem because i'm just developing algorithms and their workouts. so, please give me information i want. ie, whether this is correct approach and wont be error prone?

Answer (score -1):

here is my realisation 
    `public  static  uint    UintFromHex(ref byte[] data, int offset, int len) {
            uint    value = 0;
            byte    number;
            byte    d;
            for(int i = offset; i<offset+len; i++) {
                d = data[i];
                if(d>=0x30 && d<=0x39) {
                    number = (byte)(d-0x30);
                } else  if(d>=0x41 && d<=0x46) {
                    number = (byte)(d-55);
                } else  if(d>=0x61 && d<=0x66) {
                    number = (byte)(d-87);
                } else throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
                value += (uint)(number <<((len-i-1)*4));
            }
            return  value;
        }`